# Saving and looking for next available moves

Tags: python

I'm new to coding so I apologize if the question I'm asking is quite simple.

I'm coding a game where I have to make one large piece (represented as 1's) on a board reach to the end. There are several other smaller pieces that can be moved (2 to denote horizontal 1x2 pieces, 3 to denote vertical 1x2 pieces, and 4 to denote the single pieces), along with two empty spaces (represented as 0's).

So this is how the board initially looks like coming from a txt file:

```
3113 
3113
3223
3443
4004
```

2's can be moved horizontally, 3's can be moved vertically, and the single piece (4) can be moved either horizontally or vertically.

The code below simply takes the input board and converts its rows into lists:

```
def initialize():
 row1=[]
 row1[:0] = Lines[0]
 del(row1[-1])
 print(row1)
 row2=[]
 row2[:0] = Lines[1]
 del(row2[-1])
 print(row2)
 row3=[]
 row3[:0] = Lines[2]
 del(row3[-1])
 print(row3)
 row4=[]
 row4[:0] = Lines[3]
 del(row4[-1])
 print(row4)
 row5=[]
 row5[:0] = Lines[4]
 print(row5)
```

The output of the code looks like this:

```
['3', '1', '1', '3']
['3', '1', '1', '3']
['3', '2', '2', '3']
['3', '4', '4', '3']
['4', '0', '0', '4']
```

The issue I'm having is saving this current formation and creating a list of the next possible formations

Would appreciate any help, thank you.
I can provide more clarification if needed.

Comment: The best clarification you can offer is to show us some of your code, so we know what you're talking about. Without that, only generic advice can be given which will be of little use to you, and of no use to anyone else - which is why StackOverflow wants you to include some code in a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry about that, just added some code right now, hope it can get across as to what I hope to achieve.

Comment: Thank you again for recommending to add the code to the main question. To answer your question, yes I have to identify all possible moves and choose the shortest path in order to satisfy A*search for one case and Depth First Search for the other.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you have is the fact you are differentiating each row of the board as a separate variable.  What you need to do is define the entire board as a list of lists referenced to by a single variable.  There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Using your approach of a function to initialize the board.

```
def initialize(lines):
    brd = []
    for l in lines:
        row = [int(x) for x in l]
        brd.append(row)
    return brd
```

The above function call returns a list of lists describing your board, so you would use it like:

```
lines = ['3113', '3113', '3223', '3443', '4004']
board = initialize(lines)
for l in boards:
print(l)
```

produces:

```
[3, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 4, 3]
[4, 0, 0, 4]
```

If you want to output the data in a form that resembles the initial data input you can use

```
for l in board:
    print(''.join(str(x) for x in l))
```

Which produces:

```
3113
3113
3223
3443
4004
```

At this point you can add functions to move pieces and return the updated board.

A better approach would be to encapsulate the board in a class definition and utilize the power of builtin functions to aide in producing your board.  In this approach you would define a Board class as follows:

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self.brd = []
        for l in lines:
            row = [int(x) for x in l]
            self.brd.append(row)
            
    def __repr__(self):
        s = ""
        for rw in self.brd:
            s += f"{rw}\n"
        return s
```

You would then define your board using:

```
board = Board(lines)
```

and you can display the board using

```
print(board)
```

which produces the previous, neat board display without need to cycle through the row and you can add methods within your class description for moving pieces on your board.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to initialize the board with the first method you suggested. However, I'm still wondering how would I save the board configuration to a list? When I move a piece then the new board is compared to the existing list of board configurations and checked before adding it to the list?

Comment: The output of the initialization function is a representation of your board in listoflist form.  If you want to make a copy of the board use deepcopy and then update the copy with new data

Comment: How would I get it back to the form I want it be in though? For example, right now it's [3, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 1, 1, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 4, 4, 3]
[4, 0, 0, 4]. I need to remove the brackets and commas in order to get it to look like the original input?

Comment: So, do I understand correctly that you want the output to be essentially five strings  of numeric digits separated by the carriage return character?

Comment: See edit to answer showing how to format output to coincide with input.